# WAR/JAR-files generated by maven do not ship the most actual version of the code

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, jar

I am using an Spring Boot Application with Angular 7 Frontend and kept building (and executing) the whole project in the following way:

```
mvn clean package
cd target
java jar -jarFile
```

which worked perfectly fine. It started a tomcat and I could access the site via `localhost:8080`. Now I made some changes on the code and the tomcat is not running an updated version of my code (but instead running the old code). I confirmed that by adding a logging on my very first page:

**The old code**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.logger.info('init dashboard component');
    this.updateAllProjects();
    this.updateMyProjects();
}
```

**This is the new code:**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.logger.info('init dashboard component');
    this.updateAllProjects();
    this.updateMyProjects();
    this.logger.info('everything up to date');
}
```

It is placed in the `ngOnInit()`-function. Now I went back and ran `mvn clean package` and tried to start the jar again. Yet, I get the following output:

[image]

From running `ng serve` I get this outcome (which is as expected):

[image]

I tried running `ng build` and manually deploy on tomcat - same outcome.

So I had a look into my generated classes - the `main.js` in `target\classes\static` contains the following code:

```
 DashboardComponent.prototype.ngOnInit = function () {
        this.logger.info('init dashboard component');
        this.updateAllProjects();
        this.updateMyProjects();
        this.logger.info('everything up to date');
    };
```

which is exaclty as it's supposed to be.

So I went further into my generated JAR-file. `main.js` from `BOOT-INF\classes\static\` contains the following code:

```
DashboardComponent.prototype.ngOnInit = function () {
    this.logger.info('init dashboard component');
    this.updateAllProjects();
    this.updateMyProjects();
    this.logger.info('everything up to date');
}
```

But still this is not executed when I run `java -jar'. I also tried to exchange some UI-elements, but the changes did not get applied. I never had these troubles actually, can someone relate/help? I even tried restarting the pc... :D

Also deploying a war-file manually has the same output.

**Edit:**

I use `spring-boot-starter-web`-dependency in my `pom.xml`, which is the source for that tomcat.

**Edit**

This problem only affects frontend code. I already tried clearing the `target` and the `main/resources/static` folder and the new code gets generated within these directories.

Comment: Looks like tomcat is caching resources. Try to clean webapp directory, refresh server libs and redeploy.

Comment: I deployed onto completely new tomcat and it was still the old code, so it seems to be a maven-related problem

Comment: Did you try to reload the page with Shift+F5 in Chrome? I had similar issues with a GWT Application because of the browser cache.

Comment: @DrHopfen I tried a complete system restart, I thought that'd be enough. I did build a new project now and it worked out. Next time i'm going to remember your advice and try that out!

Answer (score 0):

The Frontend Code is cached by the browser (Chrome). To reload the page ignoring the cache you can use `Shift + F5`. (See https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en Webpage shortcuts for details.)